# DC doesn't answer DNS queries from its address. It does answer from loopback

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller

Both of our domain controllers stopped responding to DNS requests. After quite a lot of troubleshooting, we found that it resolves DNS requests to its loopback address, but not to its own address.

When we start nslookup and server 127.0.0.1, it resolves every hostname we enter.
When we start nslookup and server <server's IP> DNS requests timeout.

On every system outside the DNS, it can ping the server by IP, but DNS requests don't get a response.

We ran netstat -a and found the server's IP listening on port 53, as it should be.

We've disabled our firewall profiles.

Any ideas what could cause this issue?

Comment: Check for typos.

Comment: Have you verified the addresses that the DNS server is configured to listen on? DNS > Server > RC-Properties > Interfaces tab. Also, did you disable the firewall profiles, or disable the firewall service? If you just disabled the service, add an any/any inbound rule instead.